# Measure or irrationality and discriminant

Tags: arithmetic, diophantine-approximation

For an algebraic number $\alpha$ of degree $2$, I know how to prove that there is a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| \geq \frac{c}{q^2}.$$

However, I get the constant $c$ from the Taylor expansion of the minimal polynomial at $\alpha$. Apparently it is possible to relate $c$ to the discriminant of the polynomial, how can I do it?

Also, is there something known about the best possible $c$ in more general cases? Is there also an expression in terms of discriminant-like quantity linked to the minimal polynomial?

Comment: By "order $2$," do you mean *degree* $2$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes sorry, with minimal polynomial over the rationals of degree 2.

Comment: OK. The constant $c$ derives from the continued fraction for $\sqrt{\Delta}$, where $\Delta$ is the discriminant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wow, I know nothing about this. Do you have a reference or something more precise?

Comment: Pretty nearly any intro Number Theory text will tell you about this, if it covers continued fractions, and diophantine approximation.